# SQL, finding entries when value to one column is A or B

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

Basically, I want to select values in a TABLE called `foo` WHERE the `foo` column is equal to either `foo1` or `foo2`.

Is this possible, with as little query code as possible?

I'm thinking this may need regex, but if there is a shorter way, then so be it.

Comment: btw it has nothing to do with regex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use either IN or combination of conditions with OR

```
select * from table where col in ('foo1', 'foo2')

select * from table where col = 'foo1' or col = 'foo2'
```